# Hive table in Power Bi

Tags: hive, powerbi

I want to create a hive table which will store data with orc format and snappy compression. Will power bi be able to read from that table? Also do you suggest any other format/compression for my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORC is a special file format only going to work with hive and its highly optimized for HDFS read operations. And power BI can connect to hive using hive odbc data connection. So, i think if you have to use hive all the time, you can use this format to store the data. But if you want flexibility of both hive and impala and use cludera provided impala ODBC driver, you can think of using parquet.

Now, both orc and parquet has their own advantages and disadvantages. And main deciding factor can be  **tools that access the data, how nested data is, and how many columns are there** .

If you have many columns with nested data and if you want to use both hive and impala to access data, go with parquet. And if you have few columns with  flat data structure and huge amount of data, go with orc.